# Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

The first bullet point of [Memory Consistency Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) is:

> - Each action in a thread *happens-before* every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.

I guess this is a relatively recent addition to Java memory model because [Jon Skeet didn't mention it in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263821).

What exactly does this bullet point mean in practice? I'm having a hard time making sense of it. Does it simply mean "There are no concurrency issues within a single thread"? Or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly does this bullet point mean in practice?

Everything in a thread notionally occurs in the order the program executes (in reality it, instructions can be reordered to make the program run faster)

> I'm having a hard time making sense of it.

Most likely you are over thinking it.  Imagine you are reading the lyrics of a song.  The words in each line happen after all the words before it, and all the words after that line happen after it.

> Does it simply mean "There are no concurrency issues within a single thread"?

Yes, there shouldn't but there can be. e.g. The Spectre and Meltdown security issue exploited this.